# How can we get the upper bound of the error?

Tags: sequences-and-series, exponential-function

I want to show that $0<e-s_n<\frac{1}{n!n}$ where $s_n=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{k!}$.

We have that

$$e-s_n=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k!}-\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{k!}=\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k!}$$

We have that every term of $\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k!}$ is positiv, so we have that $0<e-s_n$.

How could we get the upper bound?

At an other question I have shown that 
\begin{equation*}\left (1+\frac{1}{n}\right )^{n+1} \geq \sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{k!}+\frac{1}{n!}\cdot \frac{1}{n} \end{equation*} The left side is also bigger when $n\rightarrow \infty$. So, we get\begin{align*}&\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left (1+\frac{1}{n}\right )^{n+1} \geq \sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{k!}+\frac{1}{n!\cdot n}\Rightarrow \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left (1+\frac{1}{n}\right )^{n+1} - \sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{k!}\geq\frac{1}{n!\cdot n} \\ & \Rightarrow e-s_n\geq\frac{1}{n!\cdot n}\end{align*} But in this way we get the wrong inequality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Taylor series with integral remainder,
$$ e-\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{k!} = \frac{1}{n!}\int_{0}^{1}(1-x)^{n}e^x\,dx\leq\frac{1}{n!}\int_{0}^{1}(1-x)^{n}e\,dx=\frac{e}{(n+1)!}. $$
This is just a crude estimation: if we exploit the convexity of $e^x$ over $[0,1]$ we get
$$ e-\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{k!}\leq\frac{1}{n!}\int_{0}^{1}(1-x)^n\left[1+(e-1)x\right]\,dx = \frac{n+e+1}{(n+2)!}.$$

Comment: So, can we not get exactly the bound $\frac{1}{n!n}$ ?

Comment: @MaryStar: you can also notice that $$\sum_{k> n}\frac{1}{k!}\leq \frac{1}{n!}\left[\frac{1}{(n+1)}+\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}+\frac{1}{(n+1)^3}+\ldots\right] = \frac{1}{n\cdot n!}.$$ Should I add it to the answer above?

Comment: How do we get that inequality? We have that $$k>n\Rightarrow k!>n! \Rightarrow \frac{1}{k!}<\frac{1}{n!}\Rightarrow  \sum_{k> n}\frac{1}{k!}<\sum_{k> n}\frac{1}{n!}\Rightarrow \sum_{k> n}\frac{1}{k!}<\frac{1}{n!}\cdot \sum_{k> n}1$$ (If you want you can add it to your answer! )

Comment: @MaryStar: $$\frac{1}{(n+1)!} = \frac{1}{(n+1)}\cdot\frac{1}{n!},\qquad \frac{1}{(n+2)!} = \frac{1}{(n+2)(n+1)}\cdot \frac{1}{n!} \leq \frac{1}{(n+1)^2}\cdot\frac{1}{n!}$$ and so on.

Comment: Ah ok! So, we have the following: \begin{align*}\sum_{k=n+1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k!}&\leq \frac{1}{n!}\left[\frac{1}{(n+1)}+\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}+\frac{1}{(n+1)^3}+\ldots\right] \\ & =\frac{1}{n!}\cdot \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n+1)^i}=\frac{1}{n!}\cdot \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\left (\frac{1}{n+1}\right )^i=\frac{1}{n!}\cdot \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{n+1}}=\frac{1}{n!}\cdot \frac{1}{\frac{n+1-1}{n+1}} \\ & =\frac{1}{n!}\cdot \frac{n+1}{n}\end{align*} Is this correct? How did you find $\frac{1}{n\cdot n!}$ ?

Comment: @MaryStar: $$\sum_{k\geq 1}\frac{1}{(n+1)^k}=\frac{\frac{1}{n+1}}{1-\frac{1}{n+1}}=\frac{1}{n}.$$

Comment: I see!! Thank you so much!! :-)